# can i create a web application to make an automatic data exchange between azure sql and sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-sql-database, job-queue

i would like to create a web application to make an automatic data exchange between azure sql and sharepoint online,but I don’t know how ,have you an ideas guys ??

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. If the web application will give in the form of commands what should be done to exchange data between azure sql and share point. The only problem is the implementation. Check the Microsoft website for the API they provide.